# How to understand this mean squared prediction error MSPE formula in this discrete case?

Tags: probability, statistics

This example is from my textbook: mathematical statistics: basic ideas and selected topics: volume 1, page 35.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
 & \text{y=0} & \text{y=1} & \text{y=2}& \text{y=3} &p_Z(z)\\ \hline
\text{z=1/4} & 0.10 & 0.05 & 0.05 &0.05 &0.25 \\ \hline
\text{z=1/2} & 0.025 & 0.025 &0.10 &0.10 &0.25\\ \hline
\text{z=1} & 0.025 & 0.025 &0.15 &0.30&0.50\\ \hline
p_Y(y) & 0.15 & 0.10 &0.30 &0.45&1\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I can understand how to compute this:
$E(Y|Z=1)=\Sigma_{i=1}^3 iP(Y=i|Z=1)=2.45$. Similarly, $E(Y|Z=1/2)=2.10$, $E(Y|Z=1/4)=1.20$

But I don't understand this formula of MSPE:

$$E(Y-E(Y|Z))^2=\Sigma_z \Sigma_{y=0}^3 (y-E(Y|Z=z))^2p(z,y)=0.88625$$

Can anyone help me to interpret the formula above?

Comment: Suppose you use some random variable $X$ to predict the value of $Y$. Then the mean squared prediction error is given by $E(Y-X)^2$. And $E(Y\mid Z)$ is just another random variable, so $E(Y-E(Y\mid Z))^2$ is the squared prediction error if one were to use the conditional expectation $E(Y\mid Z)$ to predict $Y$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang thanks for your explanation. That makes sense. That is the definition of MSPE. But I don't understand the first equal sign of the last formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is wrong. It should be

$$\mathsf E\left[\left(Y-\mathsf E[Y\mid Z]\right)^2\right]\;,$$

i.e. the squaring occurs before taking the expectation, not after. Then the calculation you write is just the standard calculation of an expectation value.

Comment: The original formula is just your version. But I don't understand "the standard calculation of an expectation value" here. Here we have two Sigma notation, which makes me very confused. Also, I am confused the last term $p(z,y)$ in the formula.

Comment: @Jackie: $\mathsf E[f(Z,Y)]=\sum_z\sum_yf(z,y)p(z,y)$. That's just the two-variable version of the standard calculation of the expectation value, $\mathsf E[f(X)]=\sum_xf(x)p(x)$.